# Trying to check $_GET for empty parameters

Tags: php

I'm putting together a script that pulls through several $_GET variables which are then used within the script for the purposes of calculating a quote, etc.

The nightmare I'm having is simply being able to determine if any of them are without a value, for example ?var1=500&var2=&var3=Yes with var2 being the culprint there.

Depending on whether or not all of the $_GET variables have a value, or not, I'll take different actions accordingly.

I researched and came up with this as an option:

```
<?php 
foreach($_GET as $name => $value) {
    if ($value == "") {
        $proceed = 0;
    } else {
        $proceed = 1;
    }
}
?>
```

I'm echo'ing a simple bit of text using $proceed at the  moment just for testing purposes.

This doesn't work, and I've considered **isset** and **empty** but I believe both options are useless  in this case. I've read in a number of sources that $_GET parameters that aren't given values default to "' so I'm puzzled as to why this isn't working.

I can't use **empty** here due to the fact that sometimes the parameters will be set to 0.

It goes without saying that I've printed the contents of $_GET and get satisfactory results, so the data is all good.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: foreach with $_GET -> bad idea.

Comment: [`empty()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php)

Comment: @Mahn why? I can't see a good reason for that...

Comment: Well, what if I query a page that has a foreach on $_GET with hundreds of thousands of parameters?

Comment: Impossible @Mahn For 1 an URL can only be that long. Second: current PHP version have `max_input_vars` to prevent hash collisions.

Comment: Right. Don't tell me it doesn't look odd to iterate through an unfiltered $_GET though :) but I guess if one always checks the name of the argument it should be okay

Comment: One thing against doing foreach on $_GET is that if you are expecting an argument and it is just not set, it naturally won't show up in the foreach like @minitech points out.

Answer (score 2):

*Missing* parameters don't appear in `$_GET`. Say the querystring looks like this:

```
index.php?page=5
```

If you expected an `id` parameter, it's not automagically going to show up in `$_GET`. You just need to check using `isset` (and against an empty string) when you use them - not pre-emptively. That just doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?

```
<?php 
$expectedVars = array('var1', 'var2');

foreach($expectedVars as $key => $val) {
    if($_GET[$val] == "") {
        $proceed = 0;
    } else {
        $proceed = 1;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: that looks promising, will give it a try!

Answer (score 0):

**If** im reading your question correctly your looking too:

Check the parameter tobe set and have a value, but also use a foreach to loop the $_GET for convenience.

Perhaps, make an array of the params your expecting, and then loop through that, and check if also $_GET contains the same key.

```
<?php 
$allowed = array('var1','var2','var3');
$error = array();

foreach($allowed as $key) {
    if(array_key_exists($key,$_GET)) {
        //Validate, value must contain t least 1 len
        if(strlen($_GET[$key]) >= 1){
            $$key = $_GET[$key];
        }else{
            //Assign an error if param has a blank value
            $error[$key] = $key." parameter must contain a value";
        }

    }else{
        //Assign an error if params not been passed to the url
        $error[$key] = $key." parameter not set";
    }
}


if(!empty($error)){
    //A Params missing or has no value, dont continue
    echo 'All parameters required!<br />';
    foreach($error as $value){
        echo '* '.$value.'<br />';
    }
}else{
    //No errors do something
    echo 'var1 is set: '.$var1;
    echo 'var2 is set: '.$var2;
    echo 'var3 is set: '.$var3;
}
?>
```

Comment: essentially i want to check if any of the parameters are an empty string. The way the form passes the data across ensures that the parameter is in the string not matter whether it has been filled out or not: however a number of the parameters are mandatory, so for those specific parameters I'd like to check to see if any equal "".

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to define and set a list of variables to the value passed via $_GET if it exists, or to an empty string if either not present or has no value in the querystring:

```
$getvars = array();
$expectedvars = array(                    // define variables to be set from $_GET
  'var1', 'var2', 'var3', 'var4', 'var5',
);

foreach($_GET as $key => $value) {        // store all $_GET variables present
  $getvars[$key] = $value;                // in an associative array
}

foreach($expectedvars as $variable) {          // now create all vaariables,
  ${$variable} = (isset($getvars[$variable]))  // if value was passed in url
    ? $getvars[$variable]                      // then set to that value
    : '';                                      // otherwise set as empty string
}
```

Which will create variables $var1, $var2, $var3, $var4, and $var5 with the appropriate values.